# Add element before each H2 and H3

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following HTML code:

```
Some text
<h2>More text</h2>
<h2>Another h2</h2>
```

Before each H2 element I want to add a link (`<a>`). I've been struggling with DOMdocument for a while, but I can't do so.

I've been struggling with a lot of variants here. Some crash, while the others add the link either at the beginning or the end of the document, or in the `<H2>` element. None of them adds it before the `<h2>`.

```
$text = 'Some text<h2>More text</h2><h2>Another h2</h2>';
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
$dom->loadHTML($text); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$el = $dom->createElement('a');
$x = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0);
$dom->insertBefore($el,$x);
```

Comment: we need complete, testable example

Comment: I've added the complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `insertBefore` on `$tag->parentNode`. You also have to create a new element for every insert (or it'll move the old element).

```
<?php
$text = 'Some text<h2>More text</h2><h2>Another h2</h2>';
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
$dom->loadHTML($text); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $tag) {
    $el = $dom->createElement('a');
    $el->setAttribute('class', 'foo');
    $el->setAttribute('href', '#');

    $tag->parentNode->insertBefore($el, $tag);
}

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $tag) {
    $el = $dom->createElement('a');
    $el->setAttribute('class', 'foo');
    $el->setAttribute('href', '#');

    $tag->parentNode->insertBefore($el, $tag);
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

**Output**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Some text</p>

        <a class="foo" href="#"></a>
        <h2>More text</h2>

        <a class="foo" href="#"></a>
        <h2>Another h2</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/128638)

Comment: I've tried it already and I get the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'`

Comment: @Alex Do you always have `h2` and `h3` elements?

Comment: I have a condition that checks for tags. Right now I'm testing on the HTML I posted above, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Alex What does `var_dump($tag)` output before it reaches the exception?